# plotly splom in R doesn't plot points if one category only has one value

Tags: r, plotly

I'm very new to plotly so the title might not accurately reflect what's going wrong, but it seems to be the pattern.

Here are two similar data frames, where the first has 2 dogs, 3 cats, and 1 fish, and the second has 2 of each animal:

```
df1 <-  data.frame(A=c(1,3,2,5,4,3), 
                   B=c(4.3,2.7,2.1,3.3,2.3,4.1), 
                   C=c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "cat", "fish"))
df2 <-  data.frame(A=c(1,3,2,5,4,3), 
                   B=c(4.3,2.7,2.1,3.3,2.3,4.1), 
                   C=c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "fish"))

mycols <- c("red", "blue", "green3")
```

A simple scatterplot works as expected, with all points correctly displayed and colored:

```
df1 %>%
  plot_ly(mode="markers", type="scatter",
          x=~A, y=~B, color=~C, colors=mycols) %>%
  layout(title="df1")

df2 %>%
  plot_ly(type="scatter", mode="markers", x=~A, y=~B, color=~C, colors=mycols) %>%
  layout(title="df2")
```

[image: df1 scatter]  [image: df2 scatter]

But when I try to make a splom, the single fish value from `df1` doesn't plot at all, while everything plots as expected in `df2`:

```
df1 %>%
  plot_ly(color=~C, colors=mycols) %>%
  add_trace(type="splom", 
            dimensions = list(
              list(label='A', values=~A),
              list(label='B', values=~B))) %>%
  style(diagonal=list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(title="df1")

df2 %>%
  plot_ly(color=~C, colors=mycols) %>%
  add_trace(type="splom", 
            dimensions = list(
              list(label='A', values=~A),
              list(label='B', values=~B))) %>%
  style(diagonal=list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(title="df2")
```

[image: df1 splom] [image: df2 splom]

I have also tried playing around with where I declare the colors, which gave the same results when placed in `add_trace`:

```
# declare color in trace -- same results as above
df1 %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(type="splom", 
            dimensions = list(
              list(label='A', values=~A),
              list(label='B', values=~B)),
            color=~C, colors=mycols) %>%
  style(diagonal=list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(title="df1")

df2 %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(type="splom", 
            dimensions = list(
              list(label='A', values=~A),
              list(label='B', values=~B)),
            color=~C, colors=mycols) %>%
  style(diagonal=list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(title="df2")
```

When I try to declare color in the `marker` list (based on [this tutorial](https://plotly.com/r/splom/#splom-of-the-iris-data-set)), the color mapping doesn't work for either data frame. Interestingly all 6 points are plotted for df1 though:

```
# declare color in marker -- color mapping doesn't work for either df, but all points plot for df1
df1 %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(type="splom",
            dimensions = list(
              list(label='A', values=~A),
              list(label='B', values=~B)),
            marker=list(
              color=~C, colors=mycols)) %>%
  style(diagonal=list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(title="df1")

df2 %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(type="splom",
            dimensions = list(
              list(label='A', values=~A),
              list(label='B', values=~B)),
            marker=list(
              color=~C, colors=mycols)) %>%
  style(diagonal=list(visible = F)) %>%
  layout(title="df2")
```

[image: df1 splom color in marker] [image: df2 splom color in marker]

What's going on? Any insight appreciated.